# Method add() does not exist on list?

Tags: apex

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `void add(Object_1__c)` from the type `List<Object_2__c>`

```
trigger updateSecondObject on Object_1__c (before Update) {


//declare a varaible list for object2 ID's

    List<Object_2__c> obj2IDs = new List<Object_2__c>();


//Get Object 2 ID's from Object 1 and add it to the varaible list for object 2
  for (Object_1__c obj1: trigger.new){
   obj2IDs.add(Obj1);
  }

  //now get a list of all the records for object 2 that contain the above IDs
  List<object_2__c> obj2s = new List<object_2__c>([select id, field_to_update__c from Object_2__c where id in: obj2IDs]);

//now loop again for all the records being updated and then for each
 //one loop through all the object 2 records retrieved above.
for (Object_1__c obj: trigger.new){
//we do this for loop differently so that it has an inherent check
//to ensure that our query above returned some records 
for (integer i = 0; i < obj2s.size(); i++){
  //now we make sure the record IDs match
  if (obj.Object_2__c == obj2s[i].id){
    obj2s[i].field_to_update__c = 'Test';
  }
}
}

 update obj2s;
  }
```

Comment: obj2IDs.add(Obj1); is the line that's causing this particular exception. If you don't understand why, I'd suggest checking out Apex trailheads. Also, this question is in the queue to be closed, because it's currently unclear exactly what your question is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem (aside from your question not being a question) is here:

```
List<Object_2__c> obj2IDs = new List<Object_2__c>();

//Get Object 2 ID's from Object 1 and add it to the variable list for object 2
for (Object_1__c obj1: trigger.new){
   obj2IDs.add(Obj1);
}
```

You have a list of one object, and are trying to add another type of object to the list. This won't be allowed in the apex type system.

Aside from that, this code won't actually do what you want it too, you need the `List<Id>` not a list of `Object_1__c`. Instead of taking the object, use an id list & add the field values of whatever lookup field to the list.

```
List<Id> obj2IDs = new List<Id>();

for (Object_1__c obj1: trigger.new){
   obj2IDs.add(Obj1.Object_2_Reference__c); // Whatever you field is named 
}
```